# OSX telnet not working from localhost

Tags: macos, smtp, osx-snow-leopard, telnet

Telnet from my mac OSx doesn't work while it works from the AWS instances and other networks. I have no local firewalls. Nothing related in /var/log/system

In the below transcript, the telnet hangs at "Trying 74.125.136.26..." I have tried many different addresses across multiple domains.. same result !

```
Rocky-Balboas-MacBook-Pro:~ rocky$ 
Rocky-Balboas-MacBook-Pro:~ rocky$ dig gmail.com MX +short
30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Rocky-Balboas-MacBook-Pro:~ rocky$ telnet alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.136.26...
^C
Rocky-Balboas-MacBook-Pro:~ rocky$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C
Connection closed by foreign host.
Rocky-Balboas-MacBook-Pro:~ rocky$
```

edit: let the telnet command run and here are the results

```
telnet: connect to address 74.125.136.27: Operation timed out
Trying 2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a...
telnet: connect to address 2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a: No route to host
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking port 25, to prevent their customers from becoming spam zombies.

Comment: AWESOME !! I had this same problem 2 years back and totally forgot about it :) DO add it as an answer and I'll accept it, sure this will help many others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ISP most likely blocks port 25. This is a very common anti-spam technique, to deal with customers whose computers have been infected and turns into spam zombies.